# hello.R in R package causes check failure

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to create a simple package with only one function. However, when running R CMD check I got one error which says:

```
❯ checking examples ... ERROR
  Running examples in ‘codelist-Ex.R’ failed
  The error most likely occurred in:
  
  > base::assign(".ptime", proc.time(), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > ### Name: hello
  > ### Title: Hello, World!
  > ### Aliases: hello
  > 
  > ### ** Examples
  > 
  > hello()
  Error in hello() : could not find function "hello"
  Execution halted
```

Given I created this codelist package using Rstudio new project, it created one file automatically called hello.R within R folder. I removed this file but still got a check failure message.

Is there a way to better deal with this file instead of manually deletion? I'm running this on:
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)
devtools_2.4.5

Thanks!

Comment: Does your package have a NAMESPACE file in the top-level?  Does it have an entry such as `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` ?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it does have ```exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")```

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing how you've set your package up. Have you posted it to a site like github so we can see all the package files? But I agree with Dirk, it doesn't sound like the function was exported from the package.

Comment: is `hello()` the one function in your package? If not, the `.Rd` file could be lying around from previous builds.  Try `devtools::document()` and then check again?

Comment: @ MfFlick, thanks for trying to help.  Unfortunately,  my company's firewall does not allow me to use Github.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to post how I cleared this error.

As Dirk mentioned there was `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` in NAMESPACE automatically added when creating a package through RStudio. I added

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
```

on the very first line of this file, then I use Roxyigen package to document the function and run

```
devtools::document()
```

After doing this, the error disappeared.

Removing the hello.rd file seems clear the error as well.

Hope my note can help other people.